# Enable Enhanced Conversion for Conversion Actions via API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm looking for an API operation to enable enhanced conversions on a conversion action

Looking at this doc, it only mentions enabling enhanced conversions in the UI: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/enhance-conversions?hl=en

This reference doc doesn't include any fields that seem to have anything to do with enhanced conversions: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v13/ConversionAction

Is there a way to enable enhanced conversions via a API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is possible at the moment @Tim J
I think it's too new. You might want to query the fieldsservice to see if there's anything mentioning it, but I'd imagine it will be a while before we see this.